# Is the Romanian verb "pișca" etymologically related to Spanish "pellizcar" ( to pinch )?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, historical-linguistics, latin, romanian

From wiktioanry: "pellizcar  (Spain) /peʝiθˈkaɾ/, [pe.ʝiθˈkaɾ]
(Latin America) /peʝisˈkaɾ/, [pe.ʝisˈkaɾ]- From Vulgar Latin *vellicicāre, from Latin vellicāre, most likely ultimately from vellus (“the wool shorn from a sheep, fleece, or pelt”). Cognate with English vellicate."

I believe it's impossible because the /∫/ in Romanian can't be explained unless the word was "contaminated" with another one. Also I'm not sure if initial /u/ or /v/ can give /p/ in Romanian, but only /b/ or /v/.

Comment: [Maybe](http://www.dex.ro/pișca/504999).

Answer (score 1):

The origin is in fact unknown, and an expressive, onomatopoeic origin was pointed as probable.

The closeness between *pișca*=to pinch and *piele*=skin, also *pieliță*="peeled skin" seems to plead in favor of the Spanish model mentioned in relation to "skin", but not at all decisively, rather improbably in fact, and without excluding a "contamination". (The problem with "contamination" is that is hard if not impossible to exclude and thus it has very low argumentative value.)

More tempting is the semantic closeness between the verb
"pișca" (to pinch) and *piguli* (to peck, to nibble, also with fingers, related probably to an expressive root **pikk(-us)* as in Castilian *pico* "beak" - see Boerescu, link below) and *[ciuguli](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ciuguli)* (to peck, related to *cioc*=beak) and the morphological closeness to *pisc* (beak, but also "peak"). Although *pisc* is said not to fully explain the form of the verb, their connection seems outstanding. (See [Boerescu, Etimologii românești controversate](https://www.academia.edu/33673691/ETIMOLOGII_ROM%C3%82NE%C5%9ETI_CONTROVERSATE_IPOTEZE_%C5%9EI_SOLU%C5%A2II_2017_full_text_), p. 296 and following.) The closeness between "to pinch" and "to peck" is obvious, and a bird that is "pecking flowers" (Oriolus galbula) is [called](https://www.dex.ro/pi%C8%99ca/504999) regionally *pișcănfloare*, literally "pinching-in-flower".

The common root might in fact be an expressive form of a larger area, namely [*pičc-*](https://ro.wiktionary.org/wiki/pi%C8%99ca#Etimologie), resulting in Latin *piccicare*, Albanian *pitškoń*, Italian *pizzicare*, Spanish *pellizcar*, old French *pincer*, which resulted in the English "to [pinch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pinch)".

The Latin connection is thus more probably an expressive root relating to a pointy object and to pinching and pecking, not *vellus*.